# Is there a glColorMask equivalent in SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit, fragment-shader, metal

Is there a way to only write certain components of the color into the image buffer in SceneKit like with glColorMask in OpenGL? I tried the SCNMaterial's property .colorBufferWriteMask, but no luck.

Comment: Can you show us how you're configuring the color mask on your material? And, not that it should matter, but which lighting model are you using?